# Error while rendering collective.carousel portlet

Tags: plone, carousel, portlet

I've installed collective carousel 1.5 (note: I was using 1.6 and got the same error, was hoping it was a regression bug or something) on Plone 4.3.1.

I then create a carousel portlet associated with a collection on the site.

When I go to pages that contain the portlet I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'carousel-portlet-view'
```

Here's the traceback:

```
- URL: /usr/local/share/plone/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.carousel-1.5-py2.7.egg/collective/carousel/po
rtlets/carousel.pt                                                                                           
   - Line 44, Column 28                                                                                      
   - Expression: <PythonExpr (view.get_tile(item_object))>                                                   
   - Names:                                                                                                  
      {'args': (),                                                                                           
       'container': <Collection at /mysite/aggregator>,                                                        
       'context': <Collection at /mysite/aggregator>,                                                          
       'default': <object object at 0x7fb332672b40>,                                                         
       'here': <Collection at /mysite/aggregator>,                                                             
       'loop': {},                                                                                           
       'nothing': None,                                                                                      
       'options': {},                                                                                        
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x86704c8>,                       
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://mysite.com/aggregator/folder_summary_view>,      
       'root': <Application at >,                                                                            
       'template': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0x69f4610>,        
       'traverse_subpath': [],                                                                               
       'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>,                                                                     
       'view': <collective.carousel.portlets.carousel.Renderer object at 0x8671d50>,                         
       'views': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x86742d0>}                     
  Module zope.tales.pythonexpr, line 59, in __call__                                                         
   - __traceback_info__: (view.get_tile(item_object))                                                        
  Module <string>, line 1, in <module>                                                                       
  Module collective.carousel.portlets.carousel, line 177, in get_tile                                        
  Module OFS.Traversable, line 300, in unrestrictedTraverse                                                  
   - __traceback_info__: ([], 'carousel-portlet-view')                                                       
KeyError: 'carousel-portlet-view'
```

Comment: FYI for simple use cases there is an alternative for carousel portlet use cases https://github.com/miohtama/imageportlet

Comment: I'm aware of that, however this use case relies on a collection of custom dexterity based content types. The intention was to customize the carousel view to display the content types.

Comment: If you still intend to solve this, you might want to provide more informations about the customizations you made. Works fine on a vanilla site with the given versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the views registered for the name `carousel-portelt-view` in [the source code](https://github.com/collective/collective.carousel/blob/master/collective/carousel/browser/configure.zcml)
https://github.com/collective/collective.carousel/blob/master/collective/carousel/browser/configure.zcml one can see that those are all archetypes specific.

given the information of your comment that you're using dexterity i suppose you need to register a view for your dexterity content types.

Comment: This looks like the right direction. So I would either need to only use archetypes based content with my carousel or extend the product to support dexterity based content.